# I cant upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20

Tags: upgrade

Software & Update not showing.
from terminal - >

```
kristina@kristina-desktop:~$ sudo apt install update-manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package update-manager is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'update-manager' has no installation candidate
```

I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 20 first then 22

Comment: It may be that update manager is already installed, and is not launching for some reason. Try running `update-manager` from terminal. If that does not work, try `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install update-manager`.

Comment: that is also not working :(

Comment: If you're running 18.04 (a *year.month* system), you can only *release-upgrade* to other *year.month* systems as the *year* systems are different Ubuntu products, ie. 18 upgrades to 20, 18.04 upgrades to 20.04,  You cannot switch a *deb* based 18.04 system to a *snap* based 20 system,  (18.04 systems have all apps upgraded too, a 18 system when upgraded to 20 has no apps changed as they are identical as *snap* packages auto-upgrade for all releases unlike *deb* based 18.04/20.04 etc;  20 & 20.04 are different products)

Comment: I'd return to basics as it's there; ie. `update-manager | 1:18.04.11    | bionic          | source, all` with an updated version (`1:18.04.11.13`) in -updates & another in proposed (`1:18.04.11.14`) so I'd suggest checking your facts (what are you running?) then `sudo apt update` & scan for missing lines etc.  An 18.04 system can only upgrade to 20.04 & cannot switch to the 20 product

Answer (score 0):

i can able to solve after wasting 3 hours, I downloaded Bionic.zip and copied /apt from it to /etc .. and i can do all things. my issue resolved this way after my long struggle.